# How to install these js libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got html site with little help of css.

I Never tried to use javascript, but I found one that called [simplr-smoothscroll](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll) which requires [jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel).

When I downloaded both of them I got `jquery.mousewheel.js` and `jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js`. When I searched google how to install them in my site, I found that I need to put them in the site directory and refer to them in the html like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

I did that and nothing happened. What should i do?

PS: there are some tips which i really don't understand in the github links of the project :)

Comment: so you've imported the scripts. now what code have you tried to execute that requires the scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) itself for those libraries to work.

You can download jQuery as well and put it there, on the top of the other two, or you can reference it from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/).

Most of the libraries require you to write some codes as well. You can read their documentation and see how you can use them.

[simplr-smoothscroll](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll) for example, you need to add the code below to your page and put your configuration inside in order to get it to work.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
      $.srSmoothscroll({
        // defaults
        step: 55,
        speed: 400,
        ease: 'swing',
        target: $('body'),
        container: $(window)
      })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should put your `jquery.mousewheel.js` and `jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js`in js folder which is same hierarchical level with your index.html.

Second, did you add the JavaScript which is provided in your link?

```
$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll({
    // defaults
    step: 55,
    speed: 400,
    ease: 'swing',
    target: $('body'),
    container: $(window)
  })
})
```

you should add this between `<script> ... </script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery js file first .here using cdn path you can download latest version and give accpording path

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then include mousewheel js

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Include mooth scroll js

Use Follwing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll()
})
</script>
```

You can set option also ,refering to document :

https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll